# Chrome / HTML memory

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome

I am testing some html that our developers wrote.  Actually, I am evaluating selenium tests from another SQA and these tests test the HTML code.

In the web page you basically fill out a bunch of information, click next, review (sometimes there will be errors like a required field is missing, bad date, etc, and other times there will not be, such as when you correct the error and click next again).

after clicking next you click a link they have to go back to the previous page to make any changes, etc.

So the tests are basically

```
while [some expression]
   fill out / change form
   click *next*
   examine results
   click *return to previous page* to make changes
done
```

note *return to previous page* is NOT Chrome's *<-* (back) button but is a link on the page.  The loop is executed many times.  Not sure how many but > 5 and maybe > 10.

Anyway, at one of the later iterations, clicking *next* no longer brings up a results page and is just blank.  My question, or what I wonder, is whether Chrome (or IE or whatever) stores all the visited pages in memory (while the back button may clear the page before going back or so) and is therefore running out of memory causing a blank screen.  I should also note that the web pages use a lot of java script, and are being debugged with eclipse / selenium / testng.

So could this be what is happening? [please think of anything surrounded by asterisks as being in italics.  Looks like it is not converting the font in my preview]

Comment: Can you share the code for the [next] button? Is is a full page load or is this a SPA using history rewrite to "load" the next page?

Comment: I don't really have access to the developers' code.  I can probably list the html here though surrounding it.  It doesn't seem to format in a comment though.:

<button id="pt1:r1:2:pt1:s12:cbNext" class="x2no x7j p_AFTextOnly" onclick="return false;">NEXT</button>

Comment: The `onclick="return false;"` makes me believe this is a SPA (Single Page Application) because it is not doing a POST back to the server. It is possible that you have a memory leak in javascript and after clicking enough times, the leak causes the app to run out of memory. You might want to measure Chrome's memory usage while running tests.

Comment: Thanks.  I will research how to measure the memory.  I figured it was something like that.